# What does a DBMS-specific driver generate?

Tags: sql, database, jdbc, relational-database, driver

From Database Management Systems, by Raghu Ramakrishnan, ‎Johannes Gehrk

> ODBC and JDBC achieve portability at the level of the executable by
>   introducing  an extra level  of indirection.  All  direct 
>   interaction  with  a  specific  DBMS  happens  through  a 
>   DBMS-specific  driver.  A  driver  is  a  software  program  that 
>   translates  the  ODBC  or  JDBC  calls  into  **DBMS-specific 
>   calls**.  Drivers  are loaded  dynamically  on  demand since  the 
>   DBMSs  the application  is  going  to access  are  known  only  at
>   run-time.  Available  drivers  are  registered  with  a  driver
>   manager.
>
> One  interesting  point  to  note  is  that  **a  driver  does  not 
>   necessarily  need  to  interact  with  a  DBMS  that  understands 
>   SQL**.  It is  sufficient  that  **the  driver  translates the SQL
>   commands from  the application into equivalent commands  that the 
>   DBMS  understands**.    Therefore,  in  the remainder of this  section,  we 
>   refer  to  a  data  storage  subsystem  with  which  a  driver  interacts  as  a  data source.

1. "A DBMS-specific driver translates ODBC or JDBC calls into
   DBMS-specific calls." What does "DBMS-specific calls" mean here? Are
   they SQL statements?
2. "A driver translates SQL commands from the application into equivalent commands that the DBMS understands."

   - What does "equivalent commands that the DBMS understands" mean here? Are they SQL statements?
   - What is the SQL dialect that are used by the applications which use JDBC API? Is it the same as or very close to the standardized SQL, because it can't be the SQL dialects used in MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, or Oracle Database ?
3. "a driver does not necessarily need to interact with a DBMS that understands SQL."

   - Can a JDBC driver work with relational databases that understand a different language from SQL?
   - Can a JDBC driver work with nonrelational databases (so with a different language from SQL)?

Answer (score 1):

"Calls" here is shorthand for "API calls", within which SQL statements might be passed. "SQL commands" is synonymous with "SQL statements".

A JDBC driver takes in JDBC API (typically DBMS-agnostic) calls from a Java app, and emits DBMS-specific API calls to the DBMS. An ODBC driver takes in ODBC API (typically DBMS-agnostic) calls from a C app, and emits DBMS-specific API calls to the DBMS (often, but not always, to the DBMS "native" network client libraries).

There are cases where the ODBC and JDBC standards provide special syntax for SQL which varies wildly across DBMS.  The app emits a standard-compliant special bit of SQL syntax, which the DBMS-specific driver translates from that DBMS-agnostic SQL dialect into the DBMS-specific dialect of the target DBMS.  (example [ODBC section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/odbc-escape-sequences), example [JDBC section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/CallableStatement.html))

Comment: Thanks. Is "DBMS-specific API"  not SQL? Which language is "DBMS-specific API" in? Could you give an example for "DBMS-specific API" for mysql, postgresql, sql server and oracle database?

Comment: An API call is a Application Programming Interface call.  It's a `C` call, or a `Java` call, or a `C#` call, etc.  SQL is a higher-level language.

Comment: Do you mean that an application can use "DBMS-specific API" directly instead of using JDBC/ODBC (which in turn uses "DBMS-specific API") ? Is JDBC/ODBC's purpose  to make API not specific to DBMS?

Comment: Yes on both counts. You might consider reading over the [ODBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODBC) and [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC) articles on Wikipedia... Or the [ODBC 3.5 Developer's Guide](https://smile.amazon.com/ODBC-Developers-Guide-Roger-Sanders/dp/0070580871) (still valid for most purposes).

Comment: @TallTed The DBMS-specific API can also be the wire protocol of the database (and it usually is for - Type 4 - JDBC drivers).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - For Type 4 JDBC drivers, the DBMS-specific API is *always* the wire protocol; that's the definition of Type 4. Type 3 drivers bridge from JDBC API to DBMS client library API (which speaks the DBMS wire protocol). Type 2 drivers bridge from JDBC API to an intermediary API (which is left to figure out how to get to the DBMS). Type 1 drivers bridge from JDBC API to ODBC API (and let the ODBC driver figure out how to get to the DBMS).

Comment: @TallTed I added _" - Type 4 - "_ to specify which type of drivers that applies to, maybe I should have phrased that differently. The point was that to an uninformed reader, that comment might suggest that an API is always a (programming) language binding.

Comment: Thanks. (1) From the book, "a driver does not necessarily need to interact with a DBMS that understands SQL." Can a JDBC driver work with relational databases that understand a different language from SQL? Can a JDBC driver work with nonrelational databases (so with a different language from SQL)?

Comment: (2) From your reply, "The app emits a standard-compliant special bit of SQL syntax, which the DBMS-specific driver translates from that DBMS-agnostic SQL dialect into the DBMS-specific dialect of the target DBMS. " What is the DBMS-agnostic SQL dialect provided by a JDBC driver? Is it the same as or very close to the SQL standard?

Answer (score 1):

A *DBMS-specific call* means that the driver translates your calls of the JDBC API to calls to the API on the database server (likely different, maybe even very different). For example, calling `Connection.createStatement()` might translate to a call to the server with a command `allocateStatement`

*Equivalent commands* here means, that a driver could parse your SQL and translate this to a totally different query language, or maybe even to low-level commands that the database understands. As an example, consider JDBC or ODBC drivers that allow you to query an excelsheet. Excel itself does not understand SQL.

Another example, one of the predecessors of Firebird had its own query language (this is before SQL was standardized), that was always compiled down to low-level commands. When they initially added support for (dynamic) SQL, this was purely implemented in the client driver. This client driver would parse and compile SQL statements to the same low-level commands, which would then be sent to the server. The server did not understand SQL, and instead it received 'equivalent commands' that it did understand.